# How to setup proxy for Angular apllication

Tags: angular

I am working on Angular app and the backend is Python which is running on port http://127.0.0.1.8000/.

When I try to make a `post` API call, I'm getting a Cors error. How can I set up a proxy in the Angular app?

I tried with the proxy setting in the Angular app using `proxy.conf.json`, but the API call is to `localhost:4200` and I am getting a HTTP 404 error.

```
component.ts
aiServiceCall(userInput: string) {
    this.aiService
      .postReq(userInput)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('response', response);
      });
  }

service.ts

postReq(userInput: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(${environment.API_URL}/chat/, {
      params: {
        message: userInput
      }
    })
  }

proxyconfirg.json
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/",
        "pathReWrite": {
            "^/api/": ""
        },
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}

environment.ts
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  API_URL :'http://127.0.0.1:8000'
};
```

Comment: If that's a CORS error, you need to modify the backend to accept requests from desired origins

Comment: CORS is an issue with the backend. Have your backend accept requests that come from that url. You can also probably tell it to accept all headers for now

Comment: To make the angular proxy work, you cannot  use absolute URL’s for your requests.

Answer (score 0):

[Using Angular Proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60696023/using-angular-proxy?rq=2)

https://javascript.plainenglish.io/all-you-need-to-know-about-angular-proxy-configuration-a1aeb2d8c86

these examples shows how to set up a angular proxy.
Hope it helps :)

- **EDIT**

in your case this proxy config is only valid when you do request in local environment , so in that instead of accessing the endpoint directly just access the relative endpoint with reWrite keyword (/api).

```
return this.http.post(/api/chat/, {
  params: {
    message: userInput
  }
})
```

this should work fine if you start server with proxy config as param

PS: also make sure `proxyconfirg.json` is not a typo.

Comment: Not able to access the second link, and the Backend code is not running not on localhost:  something. 
it is running on 127.0.0.8000. when i implement a proxy api call is like localhost:4200/something  so it is showing 404 error

Comment: that is fine , you just have to specify the url in you case like                                            target: `http://127.0.0.8000` and will works fine.. i use this to connect docker instances and can verify with your public ip too. make sure your proxy configuration is correct

Comment: if its not working can you please specify the http call with code snippets

Comment: component.ts
aiServiceCall(userInput: string) {
    this.aiService
      .postReq(userInput)
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('response', response);
      });
  }
`

service.ts
postReq(userInput: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(${environment.API_URL}/chat/, {
      params: {
        message: userInput
      }
    })
  }

Comment: @sindushvelagaleti, first of all, i don't know its intentional or not you have typo in naming the proxyConfig and in your case pathReWrite(/api) should be added in the api endpoint.. PS: i will add a edit in my answer.